# anaconda 3 scaling error when installing in ubuntu 21

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda3

I just installed ubuntu 21 on my laptop and then I try to install anaconda 3 using anaconda-navigator I got this message:

```
WARNING linux_scaling.get_scaling_factor_using_dbus:42
Can't detect system scaling factor settings for primary monitor.
```

and yes, the window for anaconda can't be resized. I disabled "enable high-DPI scaling" setting in Navigator's Preferences menu, as this has worked for other users. Not for me.
Also tried to change in ~/.anaconda/navigator/anaconda-navigator.ini :

```
<enable_high_dpi_scaling = True> to <enable_high_dpi_scaling = False>, or <enable_high_dpi_scaling = None>
```

but this also hasn't worked. As I said, I'm using ubuntu 21.04 on gnome 3.38.5 and I'm trying to run anaconda 3 2021-05 on 64 bit. Jupyter notebook seems to run ok.  Any ideas?